# How does one Android module know about another module, without declaring it as a dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, module, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to understand how to structure an Android app through modules, and looking at the NowInAndroid app to learn from it.

This page shows a nice graph displaying some of the module dependency relations:
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/docs/ModularizationLearningJourney.md

Now, when looking at the ForYouViewModel (in :feature:foryou), there's an import of 2 usecases from :core:domain, and a UserDataRepository from :core:data
Both are injected by Hilt.
These modules are not dependencies of :feature:foryou though. How does it know about these and what these do? How does it resolve the imports?

:feature:foryou is a dependency of :app, but that should't provide :feature:foryou anything, right?

(Checked a lot of documentation and examples on modules.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for whoever is confused about this same thing.
The answer lies in Gradle convention plugins. https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

I haven't looked at it properly yet, but it looks like the convention plugin allows for providing a set of dependencies to multiple modules that require those same dependencies.

This keeps the gradle files for those modules small (and might make you wonder "where does this come from? like it did for me)